# Groovy: Maps deep nesting

Tags: groovy

I got a map matrix that looks like this:

```
def matrix = [
    field1:[role1:[state1:["f1r1s1",true],
                   state2:["f1r1s2",false]],
            role2:[state1:["f1r2s1",true],
                   state2:["f1r2s2",false]]
           ],
    field2:[role1:[state1:["f2r1s1",true],
                   state2:["f2r1s2",false]],
            role2:[state1:["f2r2s1",true],
                   state2:["f1r2s2",false]]
           ]
]
```

I am trying to get all fields where role is "role1" and state is "state1". Easy? Help pls.

Comment: you mean all fields that **has** a role1 that **has** a state1?

Comment: yes, can i do something like this: matrix.*.role1.state1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
matrix.values().role1.state1
```

works for this case, as you've only got a single level of unknown to search through.

Comment: very nice that indeed worked. now, can I end up with the following structure: [field1:["f1r1s1",true], field2:["f2r1s1",true]] ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
def map = matrix.inject([:]) { map, elem -> map << [ (elem.key): elem.value[ 'role1' ][ 'state1' ] ] }
```

to get your required result:

```
[field1:[f1r1s1, true], field2:[f2r1s1, true]]
```